# AWS EKS - Can I specify public and private subnets for AWS Load Balancer Controller to use instead of automatic selection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Reading up on [AWS Load Balancer Controllers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/exposing-kubernetes-applications-part-2-aws-load-balancer-controller/), where it says the following:

```
Best practices for AWS Application Load Balancer Controller require that we configure it with at least two public and two private subnets across availability zones. The nodes of our Amazon EKS cluster reside in the private subnets, while the public subnets are used to provision internal resources that allow the load balancer to route traffic to the IPs in the private subnets.

The controller can automatically discover these subnets based on their tags:

kubernetes.io/role/elb with 1 or '' value for public subnets, and
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb with 1 or '' value for private subnets
```

This is all well and good, but I would like to be able to deploy an AWS Load Balancer Controller and be specific on which PRIVATE AND PUBLIC subnets I would like to utilise, without the reliance on them being tagged. The reason for that is purely that I don't want to tag them if I don't have to (I didn't create them).

I'm trying to follow more documentation on [exposing my nginx ingress controller via NLB with the help of AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/exposing-kubernetes-applications-part-3-nginx-ingress-controller/#:%7E:text=provision%20aws%20nlb%20for%20the%20nginx%20ingress%20controller), and I'm wondering would it be as simple as adding `--set controller.service.annotations."service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets"="subnet-xxxxxx,subnet-yyyyyy"` to the Helm command for installing the AWS Load Balancer Controller?

ie something like:

```
helm upgrade -i aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller \
    -n kube-system \
    --set clusterName=nginx-ingress-controller-walkthrough \
    --set serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets"="subnet-public-AZa,subnet-public-AZb,subnet-private-AZa,subnet-private-AZa"
```

Can anyone help me?